# How to assess geocode service accuracy / recommendations for geocoding services

Tags: geocoding, web-service, accuracy

I've looked at some similar questions on here, but we have very specific requirements and do not have the technical expertise to figure out how to map other questions to our situation.

We are willing to pay enterprise prices, but we need very high accuracy rooftop geocodes. We would be submitting individual CASS-validated addresses, as many as 15k an hour, and requiring low-latency results. We require a very high uptime. For TOS, we are not a profit-making entity, but we require the rights to store the results. Preference would be given to services that are better able to keep up with new development. Domestic addresses in the State of Wisconsin are required, other domestic addresses and international addresses would be nice. We have no need for reverse-geocoding. We have a use for batch-geocoding but only if expected accuracy is *very* high (our individual geocodes are human-verified; batches would not be). Responsive customer support is a big plus. Ideally the cost would be less than $5000/year, but accuracy and availability are the two biggest concerns.

I've looked at several companies that provide these kinds of services, and the problem is that our GIS specialist has left, and we lack the technical expertise to evaluate the accuracy of these geocodes. In the interim we are using Bing, but have received many complaints about the accuracy of its geocodes.

Comment: In my dealings with geocoding in the last few months, I've discovered that Google and Bing are not as accurate as I thought they were.  From the data that I worked with in North America, I would say they are only a little more accurate than using the PostGIS Tiger Geocoder but I continue to use my Tiger server because I can fix any geocoding issues immediately after researching with Google street view and I am not limited by any TOS (which some companies won't let you retain/store results.)  I want to say that I found Mapquest to be more reliable but I don't have anything to back that up.

Comment: Ultimately, I believe the most accurate geocoding service you are going to find is straight from the US post office (or country of choice). https://ribbs.usps.gov/index.cfm?page=address_info_systems

Comment: http://www.link.wisconsin.gov/data has an address file (State Wide) that can be loaded into a database and you can create a service  use that reducing your cost and latency.

Comment: @kttii I was under the impression that USPS does not usually give rooftop-accuracy geocodes, which we need.

Comment: @Mapperz The 2014 Address and Parcel Data file is great, but was a one-time thing. There is no funding or legislative will to have ongoing statewide parcel mapping updated on a regular basis. We would like at least semiannual updates for new development.

Comment: @TBridges42 yeah, I meant to mention that too, I haven't found any useful services direct from the USPS.